# Unable to find bundled Java version - no jrb folder

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

I have just installed new Android Studio Electric Eel and flutter stopped working.

Here's my `flutter doctor -v`:

```
PS E:\flutter-projects\json_test000> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2486], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.7.3 on channel stable at E:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9944297138 (10 days ago), 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
    • Engine revision 248290d6d5
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Albert\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Albert\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: E:\Android studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.10)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.32126.315
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.18362.0

[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at E:\Android-Studio-Update-Test
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at E:\Android studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (5 available)
    • SM A325F (mobile)            • R58R60AXPXN   • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2486]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.104
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 110.0.1587.46

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I have already looked around and everyone seems to have the same answer, move `jbr` to `jre`. But I don't have `jbr` in my android studio folder. (My folder is also on E: but that isn't a problem since everything is migrated there). What should I do?

Comment: You have two Android Studio installations: 4.1 and 2022.1, apparently. *Which one* did you check for the `jbr` folder? Because AFAIK only the 2022.1 will have that instead of the jre.

Comment: Right, thank you very much, if you want answer the question, will upvote and mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

WORKAROUND:

1. Browse to your Android Studio install directory in Windows Explorer
2. Copy jrb\* to jre

You can find more details here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502

PS:

I had a simple Flutter project that worked fine 6 months ago.  When I upgraded Android Studio to Electric Eel, *several* things broke:

1. A/S Electric Eel now installs its embedded Java to "jrb" instead of "jre"

   WORAROUND: copy jrb\* to jre
2. My project happened to target SDKVersion 30; Electric Eel requires minimum SDK 31

   WORKAROUND: hack your Flutter project's android\app\build.gradle:

   ```
    android {
      compileSdkVersion 30 => 31
      targetSdkVersion 30 => 31
   ```
3. Electric Eel requires a newer Kotlin version

   WORKAROUND:android\app\build.gradle:

   ```
    buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50' => '1.6.10'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I downloaded dolphin again and all the problems were gone.